# How can I add a privacy policy?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

Just got rejected since I dont have any privacy statement. I figured out how to add it to the charms menu, but Im failing on how to link to Privacy.html I have in the root folder of my project.

```
A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI
```

How can I link to a local file in the solution? This would solve the latter of my two problems:

- The app has declared access to network capabilities and no privacy statement was provided in the Description page.
- The app has declared access to network capabilities and no privacy statement was provided in the Windows Settings Charm.

But how do I fix that first part? My app does not have any description page ...

Answer (score 3):

The way I understand it is that you have to use the Privacy policy field in the Description step of the the app. Have you tried that? And it has to be online. Don't think I was clear about that, but the policy should b online.

[image]

Leave a note to the testers as to where the policy is, I've heard about apps getting rejected that didn't do that, even though they had the url

[image]

After all the comments and discussionn on twitter and fb I wrote up a small [blog post](http://www.irisclasson.com/2013/07/28/how-to-add-a-privacy-policystatement-to-your-windows-store-app/) on how to do this, basically what I wrote here,plus where you can host the policy. Not meant as a way to get traffic to the blog.

Comment: To add to Iris's answer, you can use a SkyDrive file for your Charms in-app Privacy Policy link. See this answer on MSDN for the exact code http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f26203db-193f-4eb3-a2d4-29e1f5628310/very-simple-code-to-add-privacy-url-link-to-windows-charm-settings-using-cxaml

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you MUST have a website with your privacy policy. You will need to get a hosted page that will display the policy. Tim Heuer from Microsoft has a [post on using Azure](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/09/26/use-azure-free-web-site-for-windows-store-app-content.aspx) to host your content (for FREE!). If you already have a server setup then just create an html page on it with your policy. It doesn't have to be anything fancy. You will place the URL to this policy page in the location Iris notes (the Privacy Policy field :)

Comment: Does it have to be a website? I'm quite sure it can be hosted in any way, as long as it is online and easy accessible. (But as you said its easy to set up a site and that definitive has its advantages, that is a good blog post by Tim)

Comment: Define website? A single html page is a website and a single html page is required for a privacy poicy

Comment: A file on SkyDrive is a website? Not sure if that would work, but there are certainly ways of hosting files online without it being a website :)

Answer (score 0):

The privacy policy has two components, the in-app part and the online part.

The in-app part is essentially another Settings Charm item that shows your privacy policy, which is something to the effect of:

```
We will not disclose any of your information to third-party
```

OR

```
We will keep your information safe
```

ETC

The online part is essentially a website link that has the same information. If you do not have a website and would rather not pay for hosting, I suggest a Google Sites site. I use the same thing for my initial apps.

And regarding what @IrisClasson has written about Leaving a Note to Testers, it is not necessary. Add the url in the description section at the bottom where it asks for the Privacy Policy.

Comment: In RE to note to testers: It's not necessary, but it wont take more than a few minutes, compared to the time it will take to get a decline and have to start over again . Since some devs did have that issue, I personally would and do leave notes to testers. Rather safe that sorry, even if it is not *necessary*. The answer I provided does not say that you have to, it says I would recommend you to.

Comment: However, I have provided notes previously, and they still reject, as it does not appear in the description.